# Строка переводится в int в Excel отчете на PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Делаю отчет из MySQL в Excel на PHP.
Длинная строка из чисел `758456123548` переводится в `int` и в Excel, это поле что-то типа `7.5945e11`.
Мне нужно, чтобы оно отображалось как строка.
Вот скрипт:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");  
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=User_Detail_Report.xls");  
    header("Pragma: no-cache");  
    header("Expires: 0");
?>      
    <?php          
    include 'database_connect.php';

    $setSql = "SELECT `imya`,`familiya`,`iin`,`email` FROM `Ankety`";  
    $setRec = mysqli_query($mysqli, $setSql);  

    $columnHeader = '';  
    $columnHeader = "Имя" . "\t" . "Фамилия" . "\t" . "Иин" . "\t" . "email" . "\t";  

    $setData = '';

    while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_row($setRec)) {  
        $rowData = '';  
//          var_dump($rec);
        foreach ($rec as $value) {
            $value = '"' . (string)$value . '"' . "\t";
            $rowData .= $value; 
        }
        $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";  
    }  


    echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";  

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function float_to_string($float) {
$string = (string)$float;

if (preg_match('~\.(\d+)E([+-])?(\d+)~', $string, $matches)) {
    $decimals = $matches[2] === '-' ? strlen($matches[1]) + $matches[3] : 0;
    $string = number_format($float, $decimals,'.','');
}

return $string;
```

}

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902817/convert-float-to-plain-string-)